# problemas con Menú dinamico en primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, java-ee, primefaces

Soy nuevo en el grupo y tengo la siguiente duda: Estoy implementado un menú dinámico en JSF y primefaces a partir de una tabla de base de datos mysql.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde:
S = es el submenu e I = es el Item de cada submenu
O = es el perfil operario y A=es perfil el administrador

al codificar el Controllador de esta funcionabilidad, me sale este problema

```
    public void establecerPermisos(){
    for (Menu m:lista) {
        if (m.getTipo().equals('S')) {
            DefaultSubMenu primerSubmenu=new DefaultSubMenu(m.getNombre());
            for (Menu i:lista) {
                Menu submenu=i.getCodigoSubmenu();
                if (submenu!=null) {
                    if (submenu.getCodigo()==m.getCodigo()) {
                        DefaultMenuItem item=new DefaultMenuItem(i.getNombre());
                        primerSubmenu.addElement(item);
                    }
                }
            }
            modelo.addElement(primerSubmenu);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El IDE me marca tachado el DefaultSubMenu, DefaultMenuItem y me muestra el addElment como error, entiendo que estos  están deprecados, entonces mi pregunta seria ¿Qué debería utilizar en reemplazo de ellos?

Muchas gracias por su ayuda, saludos

Comment: Que  versión de Primefaces estás  utilizando.

Comment: primefaces 8.0, muchas gracias amigo por tu pronta respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Siempre, lo primero, la documentación: https://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/8.0/org/primefaces/model/menu/DefaultMenuItem.html

En concreto, la clase no está deprecada pero tres de los cuatro constructores sí que lo están (*1): https://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/8.0/org/primefaces/model/menu/DefaultMenuItem.html#DefaultMenuItem-java.lang.Object-

> @Deprecated
> public DefaultMenuItem(Object value)
>
> Deprecated. Use builder() instead.
> Creates a new menu item with the specified

Que por el nombre usará el pattern *builder*, y viendo el enlace, parece que sería algo así como

```
DefaultMenuItem menuItem = DefaultMenuItem.Builder.title(etiqueta).build();
```

Lo mismo aplica a `DefaultSubMenu`, que no tiene un método `addElement` pero tiene un método `getElements` y otro `setElements`.

*1 Si la clase estuviera deprecada también te saldría el *warning* en el *import*, y en el tipo de la variable.